# how can I test why ionicons doesn't work?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using ionic 2. When I began programing my app, the ionicons worked fine. Now it's doesn't print anything. Do you know why? It's possible to add the library or something like this?

I print the icons in this way:

```
<ion-icon name="mail" item-left></ion-icon>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi if you are using ionic RC6, this version introduces some [breaking changes](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc6-2017-01-24)

> Change the import for ionicons in your theme/variables.scss file from
>   this:
>
> @import "ionicons";
>
> to
>
> @import "ionic.ionicons";

I think this should solve your problem

Comment: That give me a file not found or unreachable

Comment: can you give me your ionic info?

Comment: Your system information:

Cordova CLI: Not installed
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.6
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.5
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002

Comment: now I have actualise to RC6 and give no more the error, but the icons doesn't print

Comment: the html from the docs is `<ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
` so the template are correct, so maybe its there but the style its hidding it. Try to inspect with chrome dev tools

Comment: ok you're right. I had a .icon {color: white} in my app.scss. I'm sorry for my stupid error. Thanks for your help

Comment: no :D i got that kind of errors and more stupid hehe no problem :)